# Collocation points and trapezoidal rule

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation, interpolation-theory

I want to construct the classical trapezoidal rule by using a collocation method. I am in the time interval $[t_n, t_n + \tau]$.

I know that I have the following conditions for the polynomial $p$

$$ p(t_n) = y_n \\
p'(t_n) = F(t_n,p(t_n)) \\
p'(t_n + \tau)= F(t_n + \tau, p (t_n+ \tau) )
 $$

Then, $Y_{n+1}$ will be given by $p(t_n + \tau)$

In the handouts I have

$$ p(t_n +x )= Y_n - \frac{1}{\tau} x (x - \tau) f(t_n,p(t_n)) - \frac{1}{2\tau} x^2 [f(t_n,p(t_n)) + f(t_n+ \tau,p(t_n + \tau))]$$
and the plugging $x=\tau$ I obtain the classical trapezoidal rule.

**Question: how is this polynomial built?** It seems "almost"a Taylor expansion where the second derivative is estimated by taking a forward finite difference, but I'm sure this is not the case since there's a term more in the first derivative.

It can't also be standard Lagrange interpolation since here I have also derivative values.

My feeling is that since I have three independent conditions, a standard polynomial of degree $2$, $$p(X)= aX^2 + bX +c$$ has been built and the unknowns $a,b,c$ are determined by solving the linear system derived from the three conditions in the first lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's it, essentially. Take the quadratic polynomial and start to solve the equations for the coefficients. Trivially 
$$
p(t_n+x)=p_n+F_nx+cx^2\tag1
$$ 
from the first two conditions relating to the values on the left end of the interval. Then one has to solve the remaining third, usually non-linear, equation
\begin{align}
\underset{\parallel}{p'(t_n+τ)}&=\underset{\parallel}{F_{n+1}=F(t_n+τ,p(t_n+τ))}\tag{2a}
\\
F_n+2cτ&=F(t_n+τ, p_n+F_nτ+cτ^2)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
for $c$. Once this is solved, it can be used to write $c=\frac{F_{n+1}-F_n}{2τ}$, and with this
$$
p(t_n+x)=p_n+F_nx+\frac{F_{n+1}-F_n}{2τ}x^2=p_n+F_n\frac xτ(τ-x)+\frac{F_{n+1}+F_n}{2τ}x^2.\tag3
$$

Comment: Sorry but with "that's it" are you referring to my last hypothesis? And I don't understand the equality after "trivially".

Comment: Could you please be more explicit, if possible ?

Comment: What point precisely is unclear? I only see simple arithmetic manipulations of equations.

Comment: So you start from $p(t_n+x)=a+bx+cx^2$. Then since $p(t_n)=p(t_n+0)=y_n$, I need of course $a = y_n$. Then $p'(t_n + 0)=b + 2c \cdot 0$ and by condition $2$ I have $b = F_n$.

Then $p'(t_n + \tau)=F_n x + 2 c \tau = F_{n+1} $ and hence thesis follows. I didn't understand that in the firt your equality you already imposed the first two  conditions. Moreover, I was confused about the variable w.r.t you derive, now I see that you  derive just w.r.t $x$

Comment: The steps in your edit were okay to me, thanks!
Did I misunderstood something in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, taking the polynomial and starting to solve the equations for the coefficients. The "trivially" referred to the insertion of $x=0$ in $p$ and $p'$, which is exactly as you did. And yes, $t_n$ and $τ$ are fixed, so that the left side is a trivial application of the chain rule.

Comment: Perfect, Dankeschön !